# Unable to use caching at model level

Tags: scala, caching, playframework, model, playframework-2.4

The [Play Framework 2.4.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCache) describes how to use the cache at controller level, but what about at model level?

A solution would be to inject it at controller level then pass it with each call to the model, but this seems awkward, a better implementation would be the model handling its own caching mechanism without having to modify the controller, without the controller even knowing about it.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try the JedisPool.  the implementation of redis.

You need to disable the default cache module before using the redis cache.
play.modules.disabled = ["play.api.cache.EhCacheModule"]

In the build.sbt.

"com.typesafe.play.modules" %% "play-modules-redis" % "2.4.0",

Comment: Caching tool or system is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cache in any class of your project, I used the following code in my java project:

```
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private final WSClient ws;
    private UserService userService;
    private CacheApi cache;

    @Inject
    public ProductServiceImpl(WSClient ws) {
        this.ws = ws;
    }

    @Inject
    public void setCache(CacheApi cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    @Inject
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

}
```

But in Scala I assume that you can do something like this:

```
import javax.inject._
import play.api.cache._

class Model @Inject() (cache: CacheApi) {
  // ...
}
```

Note:

> The @Inject annotation can be used on fields or on constructors

More info about how to use the @Inject annotation on play scala: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Declaring-dependencies